# write to AWS S3 programatically -returns- Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, client, apache-kafka

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts. (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

I created a role and it's Trust Relationship is :

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<awsID>:root",
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I even tried creating a policy and assigned it to my role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::secorbackup"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::secorbackup/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Nothing seems to work. I'm getting the same error. I am using pinterest/secor for log persistence from kafka to s3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.

This error means exactly what it says.

You cannot assume a role while using a root account, under any circumstances.  You have to use an IAM account.

There is no other workaround for this.  The behavior is by design.

Comment: how do I use an IAM account?

Comment: "This behavior is by design" Do you have a source for the reasoning for that? I looked [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html) but couldn't find a justification.

Comment: @scubbo by design: [*Important: You cannot call `AssumeRole` by using AWS root account credentials; access is denied. You must use credentials for an IAM user or an IAM role to call `AssumeRole`.*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html)  Justification, I assume, is a matter of best practices: you shouldn't be using your root credentials, or even have IAM credentials for your root user, because there is no way to reign them in.  They're wide open and unconstrained.

Comment: Don't know why this is marked as answered, they have simply changed the error into different words lol, Following their docs to set up an IAM user directly and I still get this issue. It's hard to understand what exactly you need to do to remove this error.

Comment: Instead of using the root user, create a new IAM user using the AWS Console or CLI. As a best practice, create a user for each application as well as each developer on your team (or just yourself).

Then associate the permissions required for running the application to this user. You can use roles for better management of your permissions.

Finally, create credentials for the user and use these credentials to run your app or script.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html