# KUBECTL An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubectl

I have been trying to make Kubectl work and getting this error:

```
kubectl auth can-i get svc

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
E0807 01:37:54.011751    2699 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://55F0139D24BC8EE6FF9E008F6A817620.gr7.eu-north-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254
```

my kubeconfig looks like:

```
kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://123E008F6A817620.gr7.eu-north-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:00009:cluster/DeveleapEKS
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:0000:cluster/DeveleapEKS
    user: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:000000:cluster/DeveleapEKS
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:00:cluster/DeveleapEKS
current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:00000:cluster/DeveleapEKS
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-north-1:00000:cluster/DeveleapEKS
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - eu-north-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - DeveleapEKS
      - --output
      - json
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::00000000:role/DeveleapEksRole
      command: aws
      env: null
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

changed ARN to random '0' for security reason, in real kubeconfig i have the right ARN for the IAM user i am using.

**some things i've tried so you won't waste your time:**

- make new IAM user with EKS * permissions
- add new role for EKS access
- edited policy inline to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "eks:AccessKubernetesApi",
                "eks:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- and the trusted relationship to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000:user/DeveleapUser"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using an IAM user and not the AWS account root user? Because the error explicitly says "Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.". Have you tried creating an admin account within the AWS account and connecting with it?
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323363/write-to-aws-s3-programatically-returns-roles-may-not-be-assumed-by-root-accou/37334769#37334769)

Comment: The `.kube/config` file has a `aws eks get-token` command written out in list form; if you run that command directly, do you get the same error?

Comment: @Uberhumus I have created a new IAM account and used hid id and everything new but still it give the root user problem even tho I did not add administrator premissions on it..

Comment: @DavidMaze for the command i've tried and this is what i got (fake token ofc for the post):
```aws eks get-token --region eu-north-1 --cluster-name DeveleapEKS


{
    "kind": "ExecCredential",
    "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "spec": {},
    "status": {
        "expirationTimestamp": "2023-08-07T12:56:42Z",
        "token": "k8s-aws-toekn"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that there's an issue with the permissions or configuration related to the AWS IAM roles and the AWS service or tool you're using, in this case, kubectl.

Here are some steps you can take to address this issue:

1. Check IAM Role Permissions:
   Ensure that the IAM role you are trying to assume has the necessary permissions to be assumed by the service or tool (in this case, kubectl). Make sure that the role has the appropriate trust relationship policy that allows the root account or user to assume the role.
2. Trust Relationship Policy:
   Double-check the trust relationship policy of the IAM role. It should include the appropriate Principal that specifies the root account or user that is allowed to assume the role. The policy should look similar to this:

**{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"  // Replace with your root account ARN
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
"Condition": {}
}
]
}**

3. AWS CLI Configuration:
   Make sure that the AWS CLI is properly configured with the appropriate credentials. Run aws configure to set up your AWS access key, secret key, default region, etc.
4. kubectl Configuration:
   If you are using kubectl with an AWS EKS cluster, ensure that you have configured kubectl to use the correct AWS IAM role. You can do this by setting the aws eks update-kubeconfig command, which will configure the correct IAM role to assume.

Example:

aws eks update-kubeconfig --name 
Check Instance Profile (If Applicable):
If you are using an EC2 instance to run kubectl and it has an associated IAM instance profile, ensure that the instance profile allows the necessary permissions.